# Who can I read that talks about this?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind

I’d like to know if there has been anyone that has taken my point of view on this so I can read him.

Some kind of relativism based on the belief that everything follows the physical laws of the universe; so everything we understand as special, such as the models that we have based our society upon and which we seek in life (becoming the president of my country is meaningful for my life), the notion of “creativity” as a separate reality where the potentially existing exists, and the thought that meditation or drugs can alter reality when in fact what is altering is our perception of it, is nonexistent; they are just a result of our inherent desire to create such alternate reality that would give us some kind of purpose.

Our brain follows the physical and chemical laws of the universe and so everything it produces can’t escape them, either. And based on that, whatever we choose to do with our lives will only matter to us as an individual. We as a species are only the result of the development of such laws throughout millions of years; in the grand scheme of the universe we are just meaningless. When adopting the point of view of the universe, we realize that only when we understand its purpose and its cause, will we be able to understand our own, as we are just a product of it.

Searching a bit on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, and apart from Camus (as he just proposed the notion of the absurd and said to embrace it and continue living enjoying the empirical life) and Sartre (which to my knowledge proposes something contrary to what I said), I found in the entry for meaning of life the last paragraph about Thomas Nigel, who seems to say just this; but it’s the first time I read about him and I don’t know if he’s a relevant author in Philosophy.

Comment: This seems very broad. Also, I am not sure what you are asking. If you pick say Camus or Nagel, whom you mentioned, and ask a single question relevant to your concerns this might limit the scope. Welcome.

Comment: @FrankHubeny  You’re probably right in that maybe it is too broad. I’m not very well versed in philosophy. What I am trying to find is some kind of relativism based on the thoughts I described, if there is any. Based on what I have read (mainly in the SEP) existentialist authors also just base their views on just a human-only perspective if that makes sense. I haven’t found much philosophy that tried to take a broader view of the universe, just that excerpt from Thomas Nagel. But I don’t know him and I’m not familiarized with his work.

Comment: you could look into anti constructivism? this question and i suppose others like it https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43707/what-is-the-consensus-on-metaphysical-innocence-of-social-construction-2n2c

Comment: The first paragraph sounds very much like fatalism with a Stoic kind of response of acquiescence that separates what we can and can not control, the former being personal and internal. "*Where then do I look for good and evil? Not to uncontrollable externals, but within myself to the choices that are my own*", Epictetus. Aside from existentialists, you can look at [Modern Stoicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Stoicism).

Comment: The initial characterisation stands at odds with the universe having a purpose, which is teleological thought and thus beyond natural necessity. In a sense,  you have demonstrated  the limited scope of such a view with that glitch. Recent works of Daniel Dennett should be of help for you.

Comment: If you're asking about the idea that we cannot understand ourselves unless we understand Reality, then this is the central message of the Perennial or 'non-dual' philosophy for which there is a vast literature. But its contributors would usually say that we cannot understand Reality unless we understand ourselves. Same difference though. We must understand both or neither.

Comment: @PeterJ But, although still a duality, it doesn’t work both ways for me. An awful comparison is that you can understand a theatrical play but you can’t understand why it is like that unless you understand what theater really is.

Comment: @Tinucci - Exactly. This is the importance of metaphysics, that it studies  the theater, not just the play. You assume that Reality/You is a duality, but this is not what is taught by those who investigate these things. It is because it is not a duality that the knowladge claimed by the mystics is possible. Yoga in its full form is often called 'The art of union with Reality'. As you say, to understand the parts one has to understand the whole.  . .

Comment: @Tinucci What you express seems to be more some vague and confused feelings and ideas than a point of view on some question. You should first try I think to discern the meaningful from the meaningless in what you say. This 'meaning-of-life' talk has become very popular, and with it some ready made idioms which probably doesn't mean much and which easily confuses many of us imho.

Comment: @Ouazzani why confused? Ask me what you want to know and I will answer. But I don’t think there is much ground for confusion in what I said.

Comment: @Tinucci Ok but I first want to make clear that I don't want to be condescending ! And my messages shouldn't be read this way. I'm sorry if I already gave this impression. Examples from your post would be : "Relativism": what do you mean exactly by that and by the belief that "everything follows the physical laws" (you probably have in mind the belief in some kind of physicalism, in which case your statement wouldn't be optimal) and how the former can be based on the latter; "everything we understand as special": specially this "special"; (I'll continue in another comment)

Comment: "becoming the president of my country is meaningful for my life": what does it mean for something to be meaningful for one's life; "the notion of “creativity” as a separate reality"; "And based on that, whatever we choose to do with our lives will only matter to us as an individual."; "When adopting the point of view of the universe"; "[the Universe's] purpose and [...] cause".

Comment: I remember speaking similarily at some point. I found it to be very therapeutic to acknoweledge that what seemed to me to be profound was more probably just confused. I think you can try and extract from what you feel you want yo say, on the one hand, beliefs you can express clearly, and on the other hand, feelings which you acknowledge as such. For example, the confused meaning of statements such as "my life is meaningless" will maybe be closer to feelings which needn't be explained more than to a genuine proposition about a possible state of affairs. Anyway, you can ponder about that.

Comment: As @Ouazzani and others have said this is too confused a question to answer usefully. The 3rd para *feels* promising but needs extricating from the rest. The 2nd seems to carry a confusion between the relativism of existentialists/postmodernists and Einstein-style relativity. 4th para: If you find Nagel interesting you need to at least say one line or just a keyword about what/why.  In summary: my suggestion : Edit to expand 2nd para, remove rest.

Comment: @Ouazzani sorry for answering so late. English isn’t my first language so that may have led to some confusion. Trying to address your points: what I mean by relativism is that the way we understand what something is, is by comparing it to the other things (a chair is a chair by contrast with the rest of things that aren’t chairs) and when looking at the inherent value of things we can’t find any difference between things because everything is a product of the universe, of the Big Bang and of the laws of physics that have developed that universe into those things. 1/-

Comment: @Ouazzani and we can also apply that relativism to our own human lives and our consciousness. We are, also, a product of the physical universe. And we are constrained by those laws. Creativity and the “supernatural” don’t really exist, just like in a portrait the person painted can’t escape the painting. In an unconscious attempt to give meaning to our existence we have created a set of “rules” that define what a life should be and what it is. But really from the perspective of someone outside of that painting each and every life has been equally important, as that importance is really none.

Comment: @Ouazzani there isn’t any importance. Some homeless man that did nothing with his life has the same relevance to the universe as say Einstein. As I’m writing this response I’m realising some things are way longer than what I’m able to write here, so sorry if something isn’t as clear as it could be. I’m no philosopher and I’m only trying to find some philosophy that fits my view so I can read more on it.

Comment: @Rusi On what caught my mind of what I read about Nagel: I have tried but I’m unable to copy from my phone, so I will try later from my computer. But anyway it is the paragraph on the Stanford Enciclopedia of Philosophy entry for Meaning of Life, that starts with “This survey closes by discussing the most well-known rationale for nihilism (...)”

Comment: OK so you want an "external"or non human-centric view of humanity? You may find [Beelzebubs Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub%27s_Tales_to_His_Grandson) useful. It's written from the pov of a being from a distant solar system who, finding himself locked out in this (our!) *remote* solar system sits on Mars and watches human antics from there with a magical (by our standards!) telescope.  And the whole book is this being's tales about "those strange earth beings" to his grandson

Comment: @Rusi that’s interesting! Thank you. Do you know anything more of that vein? Not that mystical if possible.